# ScalaPlay > 2.6 how to access POST requests while faking a trivial server in tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework

I'm trying to setup a fake server with Play2.7 and the environment suggested by https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/play-rest-api/ just echoing json from a POST request. While I was able to make GET and POST requests returning hardwired values I can't access directly the request to return or process it. NOTE: this was doable with versions < 2.6 but now Action has become deprecated, so I'm wondering which is the correct way to deal with this in Play >= 2.6

I have read the following [how to mock external WS API calls in Scala Play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025087/how-to-mock-external-ws-api-calls-in-scala-play-framework) and [How to unit test servers in Play 2.6 now that Action singleton is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516955/how-to-unit-test-servers-in-play-2-6-now-that-action-singleton-is-deprecated?rq=1)  which are actually doing almost all I am trying to do, but it seems I need something different to access the Request. In previous version of Play I could do something like the following:

```scala
case POST(p"/route") => Action { request => Ok(request.body.asJson.getOrElse(JsObject.empty)) }
```

But it seems calling the action this way is not more possible since I received the 'infamous'

```scala
object Action in package mvc is deprecated: Inject an ActionBuilder (e.g. DefaultActionBuilder) or extend BaseController/AbstractController/InjectedController
```

error.

my actual working code is

```scala
object FakeServer {

  def withServerForStep1[T](codeBlock: WSClient => T): T =
    Server.withRouterFromComponents() { cs =>
      {
        case POST(p"/route") =>
          cs.defaultActionBuilder {
            Results.Ok(Json.arr(Json.obj("full_name" -> "octocat/Hello-World")))
          }
      }
    } { implicit port =>
      WsTestClient.withClient(codeBlock)
    }
}
```

and the unit Spec is something like

```scala
"The step 1" should {
    "Just call the fakeservice" in {
      setupContext()
      FakeServer.withServerForStep1 ( {
        ws =>
          val request = ws.url("/route")
          val data = Json.obj(
            "key1" -> "value1",
            "key2" -> "value2"
          )
          val response = request.post(data).futureValue

          response.status mustBe 200
          response.body mustBe Json.toJson(data)

      })
    }
  }
```

I would like to write the FakeServer in such a way that the Spec will succeed in checking that returned body is equal to original sent json. Currently it is obviously failing with

```
"[{"full_name":"octocat/Hello-World"}]" was not equal to {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found how to do it, and the correct way as often happens in Scala is... trivial.

The "trick" was just to add `request =>` in the body of `cs.defaultActionBuilder` as in the next example

```
 object FakeServer {

  def withServerForStep1[T](codeBlock: WSClient => T): T =
    Server.withRouterFromComponents() { cs =>
      {
        case POST(p"/route") =>

          cs.defaultActionBuilder { request =>
            val bodyAsJson = request.body.asJson.getOrElse(JsObject.empty)
            Results.Ok(bodyAsJson)
          }
      }
    } { implicit port =>
      WsTestClient.withClient(codeBlock)
    }
}
```

Then the test just needed to deal with possible extra wrapping quotes and reads as

```
 val response = request.post(data).futureValue

        response.status mustBe 200
        response.body mustBe Json.toJson(data).toString()
```